Relationship Between Neural Network Distances and Performance
I've been wondering whether there might be a correlation between the "distance" among neural network weights and their performance.
To elaborate, consider the following scenario:
We have three models, M1, M2, and M3, all with identical structures, each trained on its respective dataset, D1, D2, and D3. Post-training, let's say the "distance" between M1 and M2 is 5, while between M1 and M3 it's 20. In essence, M1 and M2 are closer "spatially".
What I would except is that if we evaluate M1 on D2 and D3, its performance on D2 should be higher since M1 is closer to M2, and M2 was trained on D2. However, some experiments contradict this hypothesis.
I intentionally enclose "distance" in quotes because I'm uncertain about the appropriate metric to employ in this context.
Can anyone help me better understand whether there is a relationship between "distance" and performance?
Thank you very much!

Welcome to Cross Validated! What would the “distance” between networks be? If you can’t define it mathematically, would you be able to give an example?

Hi Dave! Currently, to calculate the distance, I'm using the norm of the difference vector between the two neural networks flattened as 1-D vectors. I've also tried with the cosine similarity between the two vectors.

Which two vectors?

The 1D vectors created by flattening the neural network weights vector.

Given that the neurons can be permuted to give identical predictions yet a different flattened vector that will have a different “distance” from a network, this does not seem like a meaningful calculation. (It won’t even be a metric, as far as I am concerned. I would consider the network to be the same before and after the permutation.) This is screaming out “XY problem” to me. What is your ultimate goal in comparing networks this way?

My goal is to "predict" the performance of a model M1 on a dataset D2 that it has never seen, by comparing the model M1 weights with the model M2 weights that has trained on the dataset D2

You can have a single network structure, with randomly initialized weights for each instance, and randomly shuffled training samples that end up with substantial spread in the "distance" between weights.  This is because in one instance one weight may be close to ideal and get specialized in a particular way, and another instance another weight may be selected and specialized.  There is no universal ordering of the neurons in a particular layer.  Your soup-can/cylinder (hyper-schmoo) is randomly oriented in the space and for one instance you may be looking at the circular projection, another the rectangular, another at a skew angle and so on, but in millions of dimensions.

If you paid attention to the level of activation of the weights for a given training sample, like implicit neural networks, then you might be able to force a stratification of neuron labels without any loss in generalization.  You can use that to have a less badly aligned comparison.
Some folks would only look at comparative difference in classification likelihood across the training set, but that isn't about structure.
Here are some papers discussing graph distance metrics:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07414
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03368v3.pdf
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-85175-9

If I were ambitious then I would show an example of this using a basic MLP and a toy set like the Iris flower dataset. I would make a capable topology, then set weights to zero, and freeze all but one node.  I would then randomly initialize that node, and train to convergence, freeze, and repeat the unfreeze-initialize-train-freeze for the remaining nodes.  This would force corresponding nodes to have similar function to each other.  If I repeated the process some number of times (35, 300, ...) then I could look at the distance between the neuron weights for corresponding neurons.
note to self: self, if you ever get free time, feel free to put that here. -me

The weights are not unique. They can be permuted without changing the output.

@Dave - this tells me I need to add the code so I can show you what I’m saying. The way I am suggesting does not allow invariance under permutation.
